# Which Virtualbox networking mode to use?

Tags: virtualbox, dnscrypt

I use DNSCrypt on my host, which networking mode would allow the guest system to also query DNS through the DNSCrypt connection without also installing it on the guest? Or is that not possible?

What about VPNs? which mode would let the guest use the host's VPN connection?